# using foreign language in django slug field is not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, slug, unidecoder

this question might get a bit large,i will try to explain perrty much everything whats going on.below is my heading model which fills the slug field itself by whatever is the title:

```
class Heading(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    content =RichTextUploadingField ()
    image= models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.now())
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Heading, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my title is in a foreign language(nepali language to be specific)
below is the image of my admin panel to fill up the heading class
[image: headingclass]

as you can see my title is in foreign language but my slug field is filled automatically by converting that title in english language which is not what i want,i want my slug field to be filled in the same language as my title field.i did some search and a module called unidecode might be the solution to it,i tried using it too but since its documentation is not well i couldn't get hook of it.so if there is any other solution or how to make proper use of unidecode?any kind of help or clue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is the docstring of the slugify function: https://github.com/django/django/blob/93452a70e8a62c7408eeded444f5088d4a26212d/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L232-L234

Comment: And this is the actual code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/93452a70e8a62c7408eeded444f5088d4a26212d/django/utils/text.py#L413-L427. You might import slugify directly form utils.text and set unicode=True.

Comment: The slug in de admin is calculated by javascript as you type but overridden when the save method is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, slugification happens in JavaScript (at least in the standard Django admin), before it reaches the server (you can look up `urlify.js` in the admin contrib package).

There's a new option on `SlugField` called [`allow_unicode`](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f8cc464452f495fce2a3d6f7494396c8f798a1e6), which might do what you want, but it's been introduced in Django 1.9.

If you cannot upgrade to 1.9 yet, you could in theory set up some endpoint on your server that would take a string, run `unidecode` on it, and return it, and then cook up some custom JavaScript code that would override the default slugification in the admin, but that sounds like quite a lot of work.

Another option would be to hide the slug field from the admin altogether, and do something similar to that snippet of code you posted in your question, except you should probably do this in the `ModelAdmin` class instead of the model itself (and you probably want to use `unidecode` there before passing the string to `slugify`).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to import "SLUGIFY" [from django.utils.text import slugify].
Secondly, In model,

> slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, null=True,
> blank=True)

After that:

> def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>  self.slug = slugify(self.title)
>  if not self.slug:
>   slug_str = f"{self.title}"
>   self.slug = slugify(slug_str, allow_unicode=True)
>  super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Finally Don't forget to add

> [ALLOW_UNICODE_SLUGS = True]

in settings.py.